# Concatenation between name and derived name class (as template args)

Tags: c++, templates, concatenation, crtp

I'm trying to avoid a problem with this solution:

```
static const int  FOO_Test = 7;

template < typename Derived >
class Foo {

  public:
    static const int  Type;
};

const int  Foo::Type = FOO_##Derived ;

class Test : public Foo<Test> {};
```

As you see I'm trying to get the FOO_Test value, which exist only if somebody made a derived class from Foo (need some external tools to write an header).

Well the macro concatenation is not working (wasn't sure after all), any idea to achieve that?

Comment: Macro concatenation only works inside of macro definiitons.

Comment: It seems you are trying to mix preprocessor macros and templates, which have nothing in common. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you could simply use [typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)?

Comment: @GillBates no, that's on accident

Comment: @KarstenKoop I have edit the question to be sure the question is understand :) I don't think typeid is okay, I'm looking at it.

Comment: D you think I can use some constexpr function with typeid, with a switch that I can write with the exxternal tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C++14, you can use a variable template to do that.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
class Test;

template<typename> static constexpr int FOO;
template<> constexpr int FOO<Test> = 7;

template <typename Derived>
struct Foo {
    static const int Type;
};

template<typename Derived>
const int Foo<Derived>::Type = FOO<Derived> ;

class Test : public Foo<Test> {};

int main () {
    static_assert(Test::Type == 7, "!");
}
```

It helps to separate the `FOO` values from the `Foo` class.
Otherwise, you can go with full specializations and throw away those variables.
As an example:

```
class Test;

template <typename Derived>
struct Foo {
    static const int Type;
};

template<>
const int Foo<Test>::Type = 7 ;

class Test : public Foo<Test> {};

int main () {
    static_assert(Test::Type == 7, "!");
}
```

Comment: I completly forgot them! Big thanks that's perfect :)

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel I added also another example. Actually the variable template is (from my point of view) easier to read and organize, but it is not required. You can do it by using specializations.

Comment: I was going to use specializations, and then you post your answer. So yes template variable are much more readable and simple.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel Ok, pick your preferred one up and go with it. I'll leave both the examples anyway for future readers. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++14, use skypjack's approach.  If you can't, you *could* write something like:

```
#define DEFINE_FOO_TYPE(Derived) \
    const int Foo<Derived>::Type = FOO_##Derived

DEFINE_FOO_TYPE(Test);
```

But I'd try to avoid it if possible.

A full example:

```
// This probably wants to go in Foo.h
template < typename Derived >
class Foo {

  public:
    static const int  Type;
};
#define DEFINE_FOO_TYPE(Derived) \
    template <> const int Foo<Derived>::Type = FOO_##Derived

// This probably wants to go in Test.h
static const int  FOO_Test = 7;
class Test : public Foo<Test> {};

// This needs to go in Test.cpp (or some other central place)
// Note that it must follow definition of Test.
DEFINE_FOO_TYPE(Test);

// an empty main so the whole example will compile and run.
int main() 
{}
```

Comment: Hello C my old friend.

Comment: Well there is no other way to concat a name that you don't now in C++ I think. Thanks, I'll check typeid to be sure.

Comment: @MartinBonner Well seems it's not working for me, the CRTP must broke things maybe. I got a FOO_Derived is not declared.

Comment: I've shown the full same code that compiles and runs.